# When programming my Atmega644 MCU. Why does PORTD |= 0b00100000 work, but not PORTD |= (PD5 <<1)?

Tags: c, microcontroller, atmega, atmel

I have been trying to understand why the line

```
 PORTD |= 0b00100000;
```

works, but not

```
PORTD |= (PD5 <<1);
```

I have a LED attached to PD5 which only lights up for the first command.
Do I have to define what "PD5" is? I never had to do that on my Atmega328P, but now on the Atmega644 it does not work?

Here is the libraries that I include

```
  #define F_CPU 1000000UL  // 1MHz internal clock
  #include <avr/io.h>
  #include <util/delay.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <avr/interrupt.h>
  #include "lcd.h"
```

Not sure if anything can cause troubles? Am I missing something very basic here?

Comment: What is PD5 and how/where is it defined? PLEASE READ [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question by submitting such an example code, the expected result and the actual one.  What do you mean with _Do I have to define what "PD5" is?_ Should we define it for you?  What do you mean when you say _does not work_ ???

Comment: Very good point. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignments differ.

```
PORTD |= 0b00100000;
```

sets bit 5 of PORT D to 1

whereas

```
PORTD |= (PD5 <<1);
```

set bit 1 and 2 of PORTD to 1 (as PD5 == 5 and PD5 << 1 == 10 (0x0A) i.e. 1010 binary)

Define some macro to set the LED on or off to prevent having to set the 'bits' each time

```
#define LEDON PORTD |= 0b00100000
#define LEDOFF PORTD &= ~0b00100000
```

Example usage

```
if ( put_led_on )
    LEDON;
else
    LEDOFF;
```

Or thanks to your own research

```
PORTD |= (1<<PD5);
```

which will set bit 5 to 1

Comment: Oh really? This is a really basic mistake then, thanks for clearing that up. So what would be the correct syntax for setting bit 5 of PORTD (that is PIND5) to 1? At the end of the day I want to be able to only set the bit at PIND5 to 0 or 1 without altering the other bits.

Comment: I don'tt use AtMega but I know they are similar to PICs, after some research you need to clear and set the appropriate bit using the first type of assignment. I've updated answer with some code how to do that.

Comment: I found out how to do it, you can just do it like this PORTD |= (1 << PD5); so I had done it wrong. Maybe you can update the answer with it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your hypothesis about what's going on here is incorrect. The AVR headers define `PD5` as 5, not as a macro to access bit 5 of `PIND`.

Comment: Sorry, but `10 == (0x0a)`, not `0x12`, I'm afraid....  Also, better `#define LEDON (PORTD |= 0x00100000)` (with parenthesis) or, even better `#define LEDON do{PORTD |= 0b00100000;}while(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

> PORTD |= (PD5 <<1);

`PD5` is defined as the number 5. Left-shifting it by one bit gives you 10, which has no relation to the value you want.

`1 << PD5`, on the other hand, will give you the result of left-shifting 1 by 5 bits, which is equal to `0b00100000` -- exactly what you're after.